# ausfallen : ihm fällt die Atmung aus

Tags: phrase, expression

Sagt man

```
Ihm fällt die Atmung
```

oder

```
Seine Atmung fällt aus
```

Oder sagt man gleichermassen beide?

Comment: man sagt weder noch. Die Atmung setzt aus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*ausfallen* benutzt man eher für die Funktion von Maschinen - für menschliche Körperfunktionen passt das nicht so.

Ein Muttersprachler würde eher *aussetzen* benutzen.

> Ihm setzt die Atmung aus

> Seine Atmung setzt aus

Beide Formen, sowohl der possessive Dativ als auch der Genitiv sind in deinem Beispiel zum großen Teil gleichwertig, wobei das zweite Beispiel wohl etwas gebräuchlicher ist. Erst wenn es subjektiv wird, bestehen kleine Unterschiede:

> Ihm schmerzen die Beine

> Seine Beine schmerzen

Hier ist das erste Beispiel darauf ausgerichtet, *was er fühlt* und nicht so sehr, was Tatsache ist - Das zweite Beispiel ist dagegen eine klare Tatsache.

Comment: Ich würde auch sagen "seine Atmung hat ausgesetzt." Weil ich eher über die (frisch eingetretene) Vergangenheit reden würde als dass ich live zugucke.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Nehmen wir an, du bist Notarzt - Dann ist die "frisch eingetretene Vergangenheit"  für den Patienten möglicherweise schon zu spät ;)

Comment: @tofro:>Ein Muttersprachler würde eher aussetzen benutzen.

Entweder das oder "versagen", je nachdem, wie lange der Zustand anhält. "Atemversagen" dauern jedenfalls länger an als "Atemaussetzer".

Comment: @bakunin Ein "Atemaussetzer" ist ja auch was anderes als "die Atmung hat ausgesetzt". (Genauso wie eine Explosion was anderes ist als ein Bombenkrater)

Comment: Ob in dem Fall von dem Ergebnis eines Vorgangs oder dem Vorgang selbst die Rede ist, geht aus der Frage nicht hervor. Dort ist lediglich die Frage, ob die Wendung "[Atmung] ausfallen" korrekt ist, thematisiert. Ich habe Deinen Hinweis, daß sie besser "aussetzt" nicht bestritten, sondern lediglich um das Detail, daß - je, nachdem - "versagen" gegebenenfalls die bessere Wendung darstellt, ergänzt.